# How to get the name of tables in a database using GetSchema in vb.net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have the following code.

```
Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
    Dim command As New MySqlCommand
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim dt1 As New DataTable
    Dim dt2 As New DataTable
    conn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=NewPass;database=converter"
    Try
        conn.Open()
        dt = conn.GetSchema("TABLES")

        For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
            MsgBox(dt.Columns(i).ToString)
        Next

        ComboBox1.ValueMember = "table_name"
        ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "table_name"
        ComboBox1.DataSource = dt

        command.Dispose()
        conn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
    End Try
```

The values inside the combobox are the names of the tables (there's no problem here). What I want to do is to remove a specific column BEFORE putting it to the combobox. Here comes the problem, I tried displaying the columns inside the dt (datatable) but it does not show the names of the tables. It shows this results.

- TABLE_CATALOG
- TABLE_SCHEMA
- TABLE_NAME
- AND SO ON...

How do I get the names of my tables in my dt? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your query should be...

```
select table_name from information_schema.tables
```

Run this query and you get what you need. Also check code below for filling a datatable...

```
  Dim dt As New DataTable
  Dim adptr As MySqlDataAdapter
   Using conn As New MySqlConnection(YourConnectionString)
    Using cmd As New MySqlCommand("Select table_name from information_schema.tables", conn)
       Try
            conn.Open()
            adptr = New MySqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            adptr.Fill(dt)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
   End Using
 End Using

 If dt IsNot Nothing AndAlso dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then         
    ComboBox1.ValueMember = "table_name"
    ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "table_name"
    ComboBox1.DataSource = dt
 End If
```

Comment: It conflicts with the rest of my code. But I somehow managed to do it in a different way. Not exactly what I want but it compensates. I'll try finding out the problem in my code using yours. Thanks for the help. :)